# How to call Wordpress functions from outside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a standalone php page (which creates an export to csv) outside of my wordpress templates. I have had some success with using `<?php require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' ); ?>` - that allows me to do a basic query using `$wpdb->get_results`

However, I need to access other functions such as `wp_get_current_user();` and that doesn't seem to be working. I have read that `require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );` should do this, but when I use that I get blank page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the header file.
`require('wp-blog-header.php');`

Amend it to the correct path though.

Comment: Sorry Matt, tried that and it doesn't work for me, see my original question.

Comment: It allows you get them all, but wp_get_current_user is the user of the current logged in user. which i assume you don't have? Check that the function exist using `function_exists()`. Also ensure you have debugging on to try work out why you are getting a white page (without functions first)

Comment: If I try using `require('wp-blog-header.php');` I get an error message “cannot decode raw data” (NSURLErrorDomain:-1015). And this is the problem I think. I've checked quite a few answers on here and they all suggest wp-blog-header.php but it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Done a bit more testing. I'm almost certain it's a problem with `require('wp-blog-header.php');` I can use require to get any other php file to work, except a few core wp files. Does anyone have any ideas? Been banging my head against a brick wall with this for days now!!

Comment: Try switching off all your plugins, (are you using caching plugins) and see if any of them are conflicting.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work. In the end I created a page template in the theme folder and created the csv from the page. Works fine now.

However, if you know a way to get rid of the BOM (byte order mark - looks like this ï»¿) that it is generating in the first cell of the csv file, I will be eternally grateful!

Comment: Too late for you, but for others, try adding define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); before the require statement, it won't try loading themes and plugins.  As far as the BOM, should be in another question.